# Can I use a PHP library file of classes with PSR-4 autoloading, and does it even make logical sense?

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-4

I envisage developing an API client library which may use many small utility classes. Do I have to have a separate file for each class if using PSR-4? Is my approach sound, and if so how can I achieve it?

*Edit in response to answers:*
I didn't understand the range of autoloading strategies in Composer particularly [classmap autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) and how that can better manage my own codebase.

Useful knowledge from [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80911/evert) and [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto).

Sample project layout:

```
src
  myproject
    client
      apilib.php
```

apilib.php includes:

```
class Connection {}
class Statistics {}
class SomeOtherThing {}
```

Or am I stuck with creating these files?

```
client/apilib/Connection.php
client/apilib/Statistics.php
client/apilib/SomeOtherThing.php
```

What namespaces will my classes use?

Comment: you could plop it all in one file (php or psr autoloading has no limitation on that), its what redbean, adminer etc does, but its don't help you in the long run unless you like scrolling through thousands of lines all day long

Comment: I find it difficult asking somewhat stupid questions on SO but I'm old enough not to care any more. If it helps me shape my understanding I'm grateful for the answers. I've had trouble aligning my declarations and file organisation with autoloading so that shapes my line of questioning.

Comment: If you're using composer (which you should), you may use the [`classmap` autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) instead, which will scan the files within given directories and load them properly no matter which scheme you decide to follow. Though to be fair using PSR-4 paths/autoloading is probably a better idea as it's become a norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSR-4 maps classes and namespaces to file and directory paths, but you are not required to follow PSR-4.

Comment: Are you saying that If I am explicit with my namespaces and set the anchor properly e.g MyLib\\\ -> src/ then autoloading should work anyway for me?

Comment: No, composer has several autoloading strategies. One of them is `psr-4`. You probably want 'classmap' or 'files': https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: I realise now how Composer's classmap and files autoloading help me manage my classes.Thanks for clearing up a serious misunderstanding.